# Validating form on submit in angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

Hello i am trying to make my validation display on form submit but validation does not work, form gets sent anyway. This is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal col-md-10" role="form" name="authenticationForm" ng-controller="AuthenticationController as authentication" ng-submit="authenticate(authenticationForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : authenticationForm.email.$invalid && !authenticationForm.email.$pristine && submitted }">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" ng-required/>
                <p ng-show="authenticationForm.email.$invalid && !authenticationForm.email.$pristine && submitted" class="help-block">
                    Your email address is required.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : authenticationForm.password.$invalid && !authenticationForm.password.$pristine && submitted }">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" ng-required/>
                <p ng-show="authenticationForm.password.$invalid && !authenticationForm.password.$pristine && submitted" class="help-block">
                    Password is required.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span class="help-block errorMessages" ng-show="user.input.errors !== undefined">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li ng-repeat="error in user.input.errors">

                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;<% error %>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </span>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br/>
                <hr>
                <button class="big-red-button" type="submit">Login <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>

                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

This is my controller function:

```
$scope.authenticate = function(isValid) {
            // settting submitted to true
            $scope.submitted = true;

            // check to make sure the form is completely valid
            if (isValid) {

                var req = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/auth/login',
                    headers: {
                        'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
                    },
                    data: {
                        email: $scope.email,
                        password: $scope.password
                    }
                }

                $http(req)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data.url !== undefined)
                        {
                            window.location.href = data.url;
                        }
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                        //alert(data);
                    });

            }

        };
```

Can someone please point out what i am doing wrong here? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check `$scope.authenticationForm.$valid` and prevent the xhr, and you can also visually set the submit button to `ng-disabled="authenticationForm.$invalid"` so they can't click the button until it's valid. That disabled setting won't prevent submitting the form other ways (enter key, etc).

Have you checked the boolean coming to you? It should be `false` is there's a validation error.

Comment: I want validation to display "after" form submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using controllerAs syntax then you should use each `ng-model` as

`authentication.email` & `authentication.password`

**Email Field**

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="authentication.email" 
class="form-control" ng-required/>
```

**Password Field**

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="authentication.password" 
class="form-control" ng-required/>
```

then inside controller you could get this value by `this.email` & `this.password`

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too.  Change ng-required to required, make sure the isValid boolean is actually false if it's not a valid form and take out the novalidate in the form element.

Sometimes the angular $valid is not always accurate. Also, I think you should have put ng-required="true" or some function that returns true, if you are using ng-required.

Check out this article: http://arnaldocapo.com/blog/post/detect-if-html-5-validation-ui-is-present/53

Comment: don't seems like it will make any difference

Comment: Did you take out the novalidate?  Also try putting  pattern=".{2,}" attribute

Comment: Actually by taking out the no-validate and switching ng-required to required i will be switching to html5 validation not angularjs but what the hell i might as well use that since angularjs validation doesn't work properly.

Comment: Let the browser handle the validation. You can shim it for browsers that doesn't support it yet. http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/  Only load it for browsers that doesn't support the UI validation.  They will at some point support it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace every where `ng-required` to `required` like:

```
<input type="text" required/>
```

and also set `ng-controller="AuthenticationController "` instead of

```
ng-controller="AuthenticationController as authentication"
```